# why even if declared final array list can be extended with new items

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

items.add("Text name 1");
items.add("Text name 2");
items.add("Text name 3");
```

I'm curios as to how it is possible to extend `items` with new members even if it is declared `final`? What does `final` here mean than?

Comment: Final here means the reference is final not the items in the list.

Comment: in ths case final mens that you cant assign new value to your **items** variable. To **disable modifying values** you can use [Collections.unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` means *reference* of this `list` is `final` which can not be changed.As you can not assign any other `list` or reinitialize this `list`.

```
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items = otherStringList;//ERROR
items = new ArrayList<>();//ERROR
```

> [`JLS(§4.12.4)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) says,
>
> If a final variable holds a reference to an object, ***then the state
>   of the object may be changed by operations on the object***, but the variable
>   will always refer to the same object.

Comment: give an example and it will explain better

Answer (score 1):

`final` means that you can't change the object `items`  references. For example,  `items = new ArrayList<>()` after your initial declaration would be illegal.

However, you can modify the properties of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

`final` just means that you cannot reassign `items` to another `List`